# Cyclic inequality $\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^ab^bc^c\le1$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

how can I prove that for all positive reals $a,b,c$ with $a+b+c=1$ we have 
$$a^ab^bc^c+a^bb^cc^a+a^cb^ac^b\le 1$$

It tried using weighted am.gm. on each term and got $$a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ac\le 1$$ but now I don‘t know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ac=(a+b+c)^2=1$$ which proves your inequality.

Supposing that $a,b,c\neq 0$ we see that equality in the weighted AM-GM occurs if and only if $a=b=c=\frac13$.

Comment: Ah yes! I didn't even see that $a^2+\dots=(a+b+c)^2$... Thank you!

Comment: ok now it is correct

Comment: @Conrad Great! So I will delete my old (and bad ) answer

Comment: it was confusing rather than incorrect per se and I agree that now everything looks good

Answer (score 0):

By weighted AM-GM we can wtite
$$(a^a~b^c~c^c)^{(a+b+c)^{-1}} \le \frac{a.a+b.b+c.c}{a+b+c}~~~(1)$$
and
$$(a^b~b^c~c^a)^{(a+b+c)^{-1}} \le \frac{a.b+b.c+c.a}{a+b+c}~~~(2)$$
and 
$$(a^c~b^a~c^b)^{(a+b+c)^{-1}} \le \frac{a.c+b.a+c.b}{a+b+c}~~~(3)$$
Adding all these equations and using $a+b+c=1$. we get
$$a^ab^bc^c+a^bb^cc^a+a^cb^ac^b \le (a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca))=(a+b+c)^2=1.$$

Comment: I think there should be no $^2$ in the second last line

Comment: @Stack Underflow, O! yes, thanks, you are right. It is a typo. I will correct it.